# Parse JSON data based on some host only

Tags: php, json

```
{
"0000": {
    "Host":"example1",
    "Port":50001,
    "Proto":"tcp",
    "UTXO Root":"c7cf1881",
    "Height":415072,
    "Blocktime":"2016-06-06 14:07:41",
    "Version":"1.0\/j\/beancurd",
    "Connection":"open",
    "ConnectionTime":"2016-06-06 13:40:58",
    "Status":"OK",
    "Uptime Hour Day Month":"1.0000 1.0000 0.9982"
},
"0001" : {
    "Host":"example2.com",
    "Port":50002,
    "Proto":"ssl",
    "UTXO Root":"c7cf1881",
    "Height":415072,
    "Blocktime":"2016-06-06 14:07:41",
    "Version":"1.0\/j\/beancurd",
    "Connection":"open",
    "ConnectionTime":"2016-06-06 13:40:52",
    "Status":"OK",
    "Uptime Hour Day Month":"1.0000 1.0000 0.9996"
}
```

In this json file, I want to get a  Status of the Data only based on HOST with PHP, for example I want to get a status of the host example2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is to `json_decode()` it, of course, so I can use it as a PHP array. Next thing would be looking for the host in the array with an if-else statement. Finally, I would get the status if a match was found. Something like this:

```
<?php
// supposing the the host to look for is saved in $host

$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($array as $k => $object){
    if($host == $object['Host']){
        $status = $object['Status'];
        break; // the break is to stop foreach saving time and resources.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$records = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$requiredRecord = [];
foreach ($records as $record) {
  if ($record['Host'] == 'example2.com') {
    $requiredRecord = $record;
    break;
  }
}
```

Something like this?